# Powershell function call causes missing function error using powershell v7 on windows 10

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I wrote a script to build all .net projects in a folder.

**Issue**

The issue is I am getting a missing function error when I call Build-Solution.

**What I tried**

I made sure that function was declared before I used it so I am not really sure why it said that it is not defined.

I am new to powershell but I would think a function calling another functions should work like this?

Thanks in advance!

Please see below for the error message and code.

**Error Message**

> Line |
> 3 |      Build-Solution $_
> |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> The term 'Build-Solution' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Code for Build-Solution:

```
param (
    #[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$plugin_path,
    [string]$depth = 5
 )

 $plugin_path = 'path/to/solutions/'

function Get-Solutions {

  Get-ChildItem -File -Path $plugin_path -Include *.sln -Recurse  

}

function Build-Solution($solution) {

  dotnet build $solution.fullname

}

function Build-Solutions($solutions) {

  $solutions | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

    Build-Solution $_

  }

}


$solutions_temp = Get-Solutions
Build-Solutions $solutions_temp
```

Comment: Please read [PowerShell ForEach-Object Parallel Feature | PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/), especially about `runspace` .
You need to use `Import-Module` or define `Build-Sollution` inside `Build-Sollutions`

Comment: Awesome thank you I will take a look!

Comment: @7cc can you make an answer so I can mark you correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PowerShell ForEach-Object Parallel Feature | PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/)

> Script blocks run in a context called a PowerShell runspace. The runspace context contains all of the defined variables, functions and loaded modules.

...

> And each runspace must load whatever module is needed and have any variable be explicitly passed in from the calling script.

So in this case, the easiest solution is to define `Build-Solution` inside `Build-Solutions`

Comment: Or you could have put the code in your profile, and it would be available from any of your PowerShell sessions. The profile is the place you'd load up all resources you'd use on a regular basis as well as any other environmental settings. See  [About Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7)  --- [Understanding the Six PowerShell Profiles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles)

Answer (score 1):

As for this...

> I am new to powershell but I would think a function calling another
>   functions should work like this?

... you cannot use the functions until you load your code into memory. You need to run the code before the functions are available.

If you are in the ISE or VSCode, if the script is not saved, Select All and hit use the key to run. In the ISE use F8 Selected, F5 run all. In VSCode, F8 run selected, crtl+F5 run all. YOu can just click the menu options as well.

If you are doing this from the consolehost, the run the script using dot sourcing.

```
. .\UncToYourScript.ps1
```

It's ok to be new, we all started somewhere, but it's vital that you get ramped up first. so, beyond what I address here, be sure to spend time on Youtube and search for Beginning, Intermediate, Advanced PowerShell for videos to consume. There are tons of free training resources all over the web and using the built-in help files would have given you the answer as well.

> [about_Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7)
>
> SCRIPT SCOPE AND DOT SOURCING Each script runs in its own scope. The
>   functions, variables, aliases, and drives that are created in the
>   script exist only in the script scope. You cannot access these items
>   or their values in the scope in which the script runs.
>
> To run a script in a different scope, you can specify a scope, such as
>   Global or Local, or you can dot source the script.
>
> The dot sourcing feature lets you run a script in the current scope
>   instead of in the script scope. When you run a script that is dot
>   sourced, the commands in the script run as though you had typed them
>   at the command prompt. The functions, variables, aliases, and drives
>   that the script creates are created in the scope in which you are
>   working. After the script runs, you can use the created items and
>   access their values in your session.
>
> To dot source a script, type a dot (.) and a space before the script
>   path.

See also:

> ['powershell .net projects build run scripts'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20.net%20projects%20build%20run%20scripts&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershel.net%20projects%20build%20run%20scripts&sc=1-40&sk=&cvid=9F207D6819694BAE81509D8DFFCCC1DC)
>
> ['powershell build all .net projects in a folder'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20build%20all%20.net%20projects%20in%20a%20folder%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20build%20all%20.net%20projects%20in%20a%20folder%27&sc=0-48&sk=&cvid=D2CD1D8E0AA94639BBAB0ED96F3AE234)
>
> [Simple build script using Power Shell](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/363922/simple-build-script-using-power-shell)

***Update***

As per your comments below:

Sure the script should be saved, using whatever editor you choose.

***The ISE does not use PSv7 by design, it uses WPSv5x and earlier.***

The editor for PSv7 is VSCode. If you run a function that contains another function, you have explicitly loaded everything in that call, and as such it's available.

However, you are saying, you are using PSv7, so, you need to run your code in the PSv7 consolehost or VSCode, not the ISE.

Windows PowerShell (powershell.exe and powershell_ise.exe) and PowerShell Core (pwsh.exe) are two different environments, with two different executables, designed to run side-by-side on Windows, but you do have to explicitly choose which to use or write your code to branch to a code segment to execute relative to the host you started.

For example, let's say I wanted to run a console command and I am in the ISE, but I need to run that in Pwsh. I use a function like this that I have in a custom module autoloaded via my PowerShell profiles:

```
# Call code by console executable
Function Start-ConsoleCommand
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

    [Alias('scc')]

    Param  
    ( 
        [string]$ConsoleCommand,
        [switch]$PoSHCore
    )

    If ($PoSHCore)
    {Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ $ConsoleCommand }" -PassThru -Wait}
    Else {Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ $ConsoleCommand }" -PassThru -Wait}
}
```

All this code is doing is taking whatever command I send it and if I use the PoSHCore switch...

```
scc -ConsoleCommand 'SomeCommand' -PoSHCore
```

... it will shell out to PSCore, run the code, otherwise, it just runs from the ISE>

If you want to use the ISE with PSv7 adn not do the shell out thing, you need to force the ISE to use PSv7 to run code. See:

[Using PowerShell Core 6 and 7 in the Windows PowerShell ISE](https://ironmansoftware.com/using-powershell-core-6-and-7-in-the-windows-powershell-ise/)

Comment: I will take a look at the about_Scripts. However if I understood you correctly. You said I need to save the script and run it in ISE first? I have already saved the script and ran it in ISE and in powershell terminal. Both caused the same error.

Comment: And to add this works if I don't call the function from inside another function. For example if I called Build-Solution from outside of any functions I don't get this error.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. Two things to note. 

First is I am using pwsh-preview in the powershell terminal to run my code. 

Second thing to note is I made a little snippet which basically recreated what I did. And the snippet worked. 

I removed the Parallel option in my loop and it worked. So it looks like the Parallel in the for loop is what is causing my issue.

Thank you for your reply and resources! :)

Comment: No worries, and that Parallel thing is inPSv7 and forward, not legacy PSv5x, so, yep it should fail in the ISE and powershell.exe by design. You can do the parallel things in PSv5 but a bit differently.

Comment: Also, if this got you over your hurdle, be sure to mark it as you accepted answer for the benefit of others who find themselves in the same use case.